# How to open a new browser window programmatically

Tags: java, browser, javafx-2

I am trying to move from JavaFX2 to using directly the browser for the interface of my program. One requirement that I have is that, my program should open in a new browser window, not in a tab.

This is because I may launch many instance of the program which are independent program that communicate, and I want to visualize their interface all at once.

I do not want to have one window that show all of them, these are independent program that can be distributed and communicate with each other, provided that they have each other address.

So fundamentally, it is just about, in the same way that in Javafx I open a window, I would like to do the same with browser technology.

Consequently, I would like to know, if it will be browser dependent or independent? Will be done from Java or JavaScript ?

Comment: Modern browsers put the user in control of whether new windows open in tabs or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL("http://google.com").toURI());` to open a new tab but you cannot open a new window. That will only happen if the user does not have a internet browser up.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)

Comment: You can open new tab with javascript with window.open(), if you don't have pop-up blocker or something similar